# Class referenced in the layout file, `com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker`, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add CountryCodePicker Class but this error occurs **"Class referenced in the layout file, `com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker`, was not found in the project or the libraries"**.

**build.gradle file:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finalyearproject_universityhub"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.5'
}
```

**XML file:**

```
          <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
              android:id="@+id/countryCode_picker"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you added jcenter() and maven in build.gradle project level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In older version past `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in ***build.gradle*** file.

In Android Studio version 2.1, past  `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in ***settings.gradle*** file like this.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "FinalYearProject-UniversityHub"
include ':app'
```

This is because this version add `dependencyResolutionManagement` in settings.gradle. Here you can add all project repositories. But in older version repositories are added in build.gradle .